# Is it possible to do this query without a temp table?

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table of data like this

```
tableid    author     book                 pubdate
1          1          The Hobbit           1923
2          1          Fellowship           1925
3          2          Foundation Trilogy   1947
4          2          I Robot              1942
5          3          Frankenstein         1889
6          3          Frankenstein 2       1894
```

Is there a query that would get me the following without having to use a temp table, table variable or cte?

```
tableid    author     book                 pubdate
1          1          The Hobbit           1923
4          2          I Robot              1942
5          3          Frankenstein         1889
```

So I want min(ranking) grouping by person and ending up with book for that min(ranking) value.

OK, the data I gave initially was flawed. Instead of a ranking column I'll have a date column. I need the book published earliest by author.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I simplified my example a little too much! See above for a better example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why do you need to do this without a temp table, table variable or cte?

Comment: @Aaron: agreed; constraining out known good performant tools/techniques is puzzling.

Comment: Because in our application I would like to have my query be in a View which doesn't allow you to use temp tables or table variables. However I just found out that I can use a stored proc instead of a view... so this entire discussion is moot. However I still learned a couple of ways to accomplish it. And also learned to double-check my example code before posting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missed that a CTE was not valid (but not sure why). How about as a subquery?

```
SELECT tableid, author, book, pubdate
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        tableid, author, book, pubdate, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY author
            ORDER BY pubdate
        )
    FROM dbo.src -- replace this with the real table name
) AS x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY tableid;
```

Original:

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT 
        tableid, author, book, pubdate, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY author
            ORDER BY pubdate
        )
    FROM dbo.src -- replace this with the real table name
)
SELECT tableid, author, book, pubdate
    FROM x
    WHERE rn = 1
    ORDER BY tableid;
```

If you want to return multiple rows when there is a tie for earliest book, use RANK() in place of ROW_NUMBER(). In the case of a tie and you only want to return one row, you need to add additional tie breaker columns to the ORDER BY within OVER().

Comment: Sorry, read the title, and it just said without a temp table.

Comment: You have a good point, though.  I don't think you can filter on the rank column unless it is part of a subquery or cte... meaning my solution might not work and yours should...

Comment: Works great. I shouldn't have a tie in my application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where ranking = 1
```

**EDIT**
Are you looking for this query to work in situations where there is no value of rank=1 for a given table and person?  in that case, try this:

```
select *, RANK() OVER (Partition By talbeid, personid order by rank asc) as sqlrank 
from table 
where sqlrank = 1
```

**EDIT OF MY EDIT**:
This will work for the earliest pub date:

```
select *, RANK() OVER (Partition By author order by pubdate asc) as sqlrank 
from table 
where sqlrank = 1
```

Comment: That is some pretty nice looking SQL. Can you add a link that explains how it works.

Comment: Well, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) shows how the rank function works... the rest is pretty simple.

Comment: You can't use aliases in the SELECT list later in the WHERE clause unless you use a subquery, CTE, etc. Did you try your code before posting? Running your code I get Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Invalid column name 'sqlrank'.

Comment: You are right... I wonder if you can actually move the rank logic to the Where clause?

Comment: No. Windowing functions are only valid in SELECT / ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data may be a overly simplistic. You talk about 'min(ranking)', but for all your examples, the minimum ranking for each personid is 1. So the answers you have received so far short-circuit the issue and simple select for ranking = 1. You don't state it in your "requirements", but it sounds like the minimum rank value for any particular personid may not necessarily be 1, correct? Also, you don't mention if a person can rank two or more books with the same minimum rank, so answers will be incomplete due to this missing requirement.

If my psychic abilities are accurate, then you might want to try something like this (untested obviously):

```
SELECT tableid, personid, book, ranking
FROM UnknownTable UNKTBL INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT personid, min(ranking) as ranking 
      FROM UnknownTable GROUP BY personid) MINRANK
     ON UNKTBL.personid = MINRANK.personid AND UNKTBL.ranking = MINRANK.ranking
```

This will return all the rows for each person where the ranking value is the minimum value for that person. So if the minimum ranking for person 6 is 2, and there are two books for that person with that ranking, then both book rows will be returned.

If these are not, in fact your requirements, then please edit your question with more details/example data. Thanks!

**Edit**

Based on your change in requirements/example data, the SQL above should still work, if you change the column names appropriately. You still don't mention if an author can have two books in the same year (i.e. a prolific author such as Stephen King), so the SQL I have here will give multiple rows if the same author publishes two books in the same year, and that year is the earliest year of publication for that author.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tableid,author,book,pubdate FROM my_table as my_table1 WHERE pubdate = 
(SELECT MIN(pubdate) FROM my_table as my_table2 WHERE my_table1.author = my_table2.author);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH min_table as
(
SELECT author, min(pubdate) as min_pubdate
FROM table
GROUP BY author
)
SELECT t.tableid, t.author, t.book, t.pubdate
FROM table t INNER JOIN min_table mt on t.author = mt.author and t.pub_date = mt.min_pubdate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ranking = 1
```

ZING!

Seriously though I don't follow your question - can you provide a more elaborate or complicated example? I think I'm missing something obvious.